# Z-index and flash ( swf )

Tags: iframe, flash, z-index

Is it possible to put a div in front of a swf ?

would z-index work ?

Scenario : I have a simple test page with an ifram contains swf. And want to put some texts and images in front of (or on ) iframe.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: I actually tried it with z-index but didn't work. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [THIS](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/toolbox/flashembed/wmode.html). Using the flashembed supplied there should do the trick, but I've never tried it using IFrames...